# Show that $d_2$ defined by $d_2(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ is a metric

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I am pretty sure that this is such a stupid, stupid question, but how do you prove that $d_2(x,y)={|x-y|\over {1+|x-y|}}$ satisfying the third condition to be a metric, which is the triangle inequality.

I know that I should really be able to do this, but I just can't, I keep seeing a contradiction. Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $d(x,y)$ is a metric, then $\frac{d(x,y)}{1 + d(x,y)}$ is also a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309198/if-dx-y-is-a-metric-then-fracdx-y1-dx-y-is-also-a-metric)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$d_2 (x,y)+d_2 (y,z)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}+\frac{d(y,z)}{1+d(y,z)}$

$ \geq
 \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)}+ \frac{d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)} = \frac{d(x,y)+d(y,z)}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)}$

$= 1-\frac{1}{1+d(x,y)+d(y,z)} \geq 1-\frac{1}{1+d(x,z)}$

$= \frac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,z)}=d_2 (x,z)$

Comment: Thank you so much, it's been bothering me all night.

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf : You’re welcome.

Comment: I just answered the same questions, after which @pizza indicated it was a duplicate. But my proof uses a bit different idea:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241382/show-that-dx-y-fracx-y1x-y-is-a-metric-on-mathbbr-triangle-i

Comment: also duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109799/metric-triangle-inequality-d-2x-y-fracdx-ydx-y1?rq=1