# Metric triangle inequality $d_2(x,y):= \frac{d(x,y)}{d(x,y)+1}$

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

$(X,d)$ is a metric space. $x,y,z \in X$

Now I have to proof that $(X,d_2)$ is also a metric space.
To show that 
$d_2(x,y)=0 \leftrightarrow x=y $
and $d_2(x,y) = d_2(y,x)$ are correct was quite trivial.
But with the 'triangle inequality' ($d_2(x,y) \leq d_2(x,z)+ d_2(z,y)$) I have my problems.

I have started like this:

$$ d_2(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{d(x,y)+1} = 1-\frac{1}{d(x,y)+1} \leq 1-\frac{1}{1+d(x,z)+d(z,y)}$$

But I don't know how to get further.
Hints are welcome :)

Comment: Hint: the function $x \mapsto \frac{x}{x+1}$ is concave-down (that is, has a negative second derivative).

Comment: Yup, you're right, but I don't see the advantage from that ^^

Comment: It turns out that $f'' < 0 \implies f(a) + f(b) \geq f(a+b)$ for $a,b\ge 0$. See if you can prove this.

Comment: Yup, I can prove it, but still don't get the advantage (may due to we don't 'have' derivation till now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(x) = x/(x+1)$. If we can prove that $f$ is increasing and that$f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$ (which you claim to be able to do), then we can say
$$
d_2(x,z) =
f(d(x,z)) \le
f(d(x,y) + d(y,z)) \leq \\
f(d(x,y)) + f(d(y,z)) =
d_2(x,y) + d_2(y,z)
$$
As desired.

Comment: Too obvious ... ty

Comment: I just posted a duplicate, before @pizza indicated so http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241382/show-that-dx-y-fracx-y1x-y-is-a-metric-on-mathbbr-triangle-i/1241403#1241403