# Metric on Two Random Variables Expectation

Tags: probability, general-topology, metric-spaces, random-variables

For two random variables, define $d(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}\dfrac{|X-Y|}{1+|X+Y|}$

The text I am reading claims that $d(X, Y)$ is a metric on the a.e. equivalence class of $L_0$. I am not familiar with using metric on random variables. If I wanted to show that this were indeed a metric, how would I go about doing this?

I know already that for a general metric such as $\dfrac{|x-y|}{1 + |x+y|}$ with no randomness, it would be relatively straigforward to show it was a metric space. Is it the same idea with random variables? For example: $d(X, Y)=0 \iff \mathbb{E}(|X-Y|)=0 \iff E(X)=E(Y)$

Or is there a different process? I did see similar questions such as this one here: [Show that $d_2$ defined by $d_2(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ is a metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297818/show-that-d-2-defined-by-d-2x-y-fracx-y1x-y-is-a-metric), but none of them involve random variables.

Comment: What you write is not correct. You have$$d(X,Y) = 0\;\Longleftrightarrow\;\int\frac{|X-Y|}{1+|X+Y|}\,dP =0\;\Longleftrightarrow\;\frac{|X-Y|}{1+|X+Y|}=0\text{ a.e.}\;\Longleftrightarrow\;X=Y\text{ a.e.}$$And what is $L_0$?

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_0$ means integrable, what's the problem with the expression you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the process is the same.

1) Proof $d(X,Y)\geq 0$
2) Proof $d(X,Y)=0$ then $X=Y$ almost surely
3) Proof $d(X,Y)=d(Y,X)$
4) The triangle inequality

All of them are straightforward, perhaps the most difficult is the last one. Just remember that you are working in an equivalence class so if $E(X)=0$ then $X=0$ almost surely.